# sitecore CM and CD environment IIS worker process recyle issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, sitecore, sitecore6

We have two production servers for Sitecore, one CM i.e. Content Management and another is CD i.e. Content Delivery. CM is refering to WEB, Core and Master. CD is refering to Core and Web. When we create a new content and publlish it to Web database, it is not available to CD server right away. To have that content available on CD server right away, we need to recyle application pool by adding and removing space in web.config.

Is there any way we can make a content available to CD server right away without recycling our application pool?

Comment: This sounds like a cache clearing issue, you shouldn't need to recycle the app pool but I need to know which version of Sitecore you are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the symptoms you describe I would say the the caches on the front-end (CD) server are not being cleared on publish and so you are seeing old content. As you are using 6.4 you will need to enable 'Event Queues'. This means that when you publish, an event is sent to the front-end web boxes telling it to clear the caches and refresh your content.

The short answer is to enable the include found in `/App_Config/Include/ScalabilitySettings.config` (rename from .example) on the CD and CM servers but it is worth understanding what is going on and how this mechanism works in case you have to diagnose further.

Intro here : http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Getting-to-Know-Sitecore/Posts/2010/07/Introducing-the-Sitecore-Event-Queue.aspx

The documentation for this can be found here : http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Scaling%20Guide.aspx

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have enabled Events Queues. Now i am running into an issue, when i try to get to the login page of sitecore admin, it is failing with an error "Message: Error executing SQL command: SELECT MAX([STAMP]) FROM [EventQueue] " . I checked EventQueue database table, it does not have any column with name stamp.

Comment: Sitecore upgrade 6.4 to 6.4.1 did the job. Thanks.